# How can I open files in a shared folder

Tags: router, windows-explorer, ftp, network-shares, shared-folders

I am sharing a hard drive attached to a Netgear router `ftp://xx.xxx.xx.xx/shares` and can access and do anything with the files in Windows 10 File Explorer except open them directly from File Explorer. The open option gives me only other browsers and MS Store not even my default browser Firefox. I know there are sharing programs such as WinSCP and FileZilla, and I can access the directory tree and open files from Firefox `https://xx.xxx.xx.xx:xxx/shares`, but I don't see why I can't get files to open in File Explorer.

Comment: Don't use FTP if you want to open or edit files directly.

Answer (score 0):

File Explorer only supports the core FTP functionality, which is basically meant for moving files around. Opening and editing files on an FTP server requires extra magic, which isn't built into File Explorer.

Comment: OK, but I CAN drag a video file to the Media Player Classic window and it will play (open). If this is the case, isn't there something I can do to associate files with MPC even if they are on a network share?

Comment: Well, the files aren't exactly on a network share because they reside at an FTP server. File Explorer makes it look like a network share, but the underlying protocol is FTP, not CIFS. File Explorer could have been designed to open files like on network shares, but for some reason Microsoft didn't.